# uiautomatorviewer java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException on mac?

Tags: android, macos, exception, uiautomatorviewer

I can't seem to take a screenshot with the uiautomatorviewer.

I get an exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException?

Can't seem to find anything related to this by searching.

[image]